# хотел делать авторизацию но не могу войти

Tags: phpmyadmin

в браузере появится вот это

> Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\AppServ\www\test\testreg.php on line 21
>
> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\AppServ\www\test\testreg.php on line 22

```
 <?php
 if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
     $login = $_POST['login'];
     if ($login == '') {
         unset($login);
     }
 }
 if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
     $password = $_POST['password'];
     if ($password == '') {
         unset($password);
     }
 }

 if (empty($login) or empty($password)) {
     exit ("Вы ввели не всю информацию, вернитесь назад и заполните 
 все поля!");
 }
 $login = stripslashes($login);
 $login = htmlspecialchars($login);
 $password = stripslashes($password);
 $password = htmlspecialchars($password);
 $login = trim($login);
 $password = trim($password);
 include("1.php");
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login'", 
 $db);
 $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 if (!empty($myrow['id'])) {
     exit ("Извините, введённый вами логин уже зарегистрирован. 
 Введите другой логин.");
 }
 $result2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (login,password) 
 VALUES('$login','$password')");
 if ($result2 == 'TRUE') {
     echo "Вы успешно зарегистрированы! Теперь вы можете зайти на 
 сайт. <a href='index.php'>Главная страница</a>";
 } else {
     echo "Ошибка! Вы не зарегистрированы.";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Про mysql_ уже да-а-авно надо забыть, это не прошлый, а позапрошлый век :( https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: «в браузере появится вот это» — дак все же написано. Если не можете перевести, воспользуйтесь онлайн-переводчиком или словарем.